# how to add percentage in total Amount using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, percentage

I have a need which calculates the percentage of amount , how to add Total+percentage and then display in Total. like Total 100 and ADD 10% then Total Show 110.

```
 HTML Code

  <input type="text" name="TAXES"  id="TAXES"style="width:100px;" >

  <input type="text" name="TOTAL" value="100" id="TOTAL" style="width:100px;">
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck. These are things you need to add to this question.

Comment: So, what have you tried/looked into so far..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
total = total * 1.1
```

Comment: @Evan Knowles can you please tell me why did you multiply it with 1.1 while in the question user said 10% which i think is .1

Comment: @usama If we'd just multiplied it by 0.1, we would have ended up with 10% of the original number, not the original number plus another 10% (100% + 10% == 110%, which equal 1.1)

Answer (score 3):

Jquery

```
var Total = $("#TOTAL");
Total.val(Total.val() * 1.1);
```

JavaScript

```
var Total = document.getElementById("TOTAL");
Total.value *= 1.1;
```

Edit: For different percentages

```
var percent = 12.5;
var factor = 1 + percent/100;
```

Add this before and replace 1.1 with factor, like this

```
Total.value *= factor;
```

Comment: if i have add 12.5% in total so what i am doing